# PHP - Unable to get proper commission amount on checkout page

Tags: php, mysql, session

As the title says, I am unable to set the proper amount of commission on checkout page.

Here's the situation:

The commission is charged for 2 peoples - Person K and Person J, based on the product's total amount, and not on the cart's total amount.

I am getting the commission amount, but I cannot set it correctly.

For example:

I have a cart

```
 Name        Quantity       Rate            Total        Commission
    A           3           50.00           150.00          7.50
    B           3           80.00           240.00         14.40 
    C           2           10.00            20.00          1.60

Total                                       410.00
Taxes                                       100.00
Shipping                                    250.00

Net Payable                                 760.00
```

Based on Product A Total, Product B Total, and Product C Total, I have to calculate the commission. Commission rates are 5%, 6%, 8% respectively for all three products.

Now, Product A and Product C belongs to the Person K. Product B belongs to the Person J. Meaning, Product A's and Product C's commission should be transferred to Person K's account and Product B's commission should be transferred to Person J's account.

I have calculated the commission inside `while` loop which shows the person's commission correctly and stored the commission amount in `$_SESSION` variable.

Now, when I move the `$_SESSION` code out of the while loop, it takes the last value, meaning it overrides the first value.

So my question is, how do I bifurcate the commission amount and transfer it to the respective person account ?

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thank you.

**EDIT 1**:

The code that I have tried which is inside the `while` loop

```
$_SESSION['ProductCommission']['PersonK'] = ($productTotal * $row['ProductPersonKCommission'] / 100);
$_SESSION['ProductCommission']['PersonJ'] = ($productTotal * $row['ProductPersonJCommission'] / 100);
```

**Edit 2**:

The Full code (Actual):

```
if ( isset( $_SESSION['cart'] ) && $_SESSION['cart'] != "" ) {
    $total = 0;
    $subTotal = 0; $sbTotal = 0;
    $taxAmount = $tax = $totalTaxAmount = $taxAmt = 0;
    $cartWeightPerProduct = $totalCartWeight = $amtWeight = 0;
    $affiliateCommission = $affComm = 0;
    $affiCode = "";

    $sql = "SELECT p.*, c.*, ws.*, m.*, a.* FROM products p, categories c, weight_shipping ws, moderators m, affiliates a WHERE ProdCode IN (";
    foreach ( $_SESSION['cart'] as $id => $value ) {
        $sql .= '"'.$id.'",';
    }
    $sql = substr( $sql, 0, -1 ) . ") AND p.CatId = c.CatId AND ws.ProdId = p.ProdId AND m.ModCode = p.ModCode AND a.AffiCode = p.AffiCode";

    if ($validate->Query($sql) == TRUE) {
        if ($validate->NumRows() >= 1) {
            while ( $row = $validate->FetchAllDatas() ) {
                echo '<td><img src="images/Products/'.$row['ProdCode'].'.jpg" alt="'.$row['ProdCode'].'"><a href="product.php?code='.$row['ProdCode'].'" >'.$row['ProdName'].'</a></td>';
                echo '<td>'.$row['ProdCode'].'</td>';
                echo '<td><p>Rs. '.$row['ProdRate'].'</p></td>';
                echo '<td>'.$_SESSION['cart'][$row['ProdCode']]['quantity'].'</td>';

                $sbTotal = $row['ProdRate'] * $_SESSION['cart'][$row['ProdCode']]['quantity'];
                $subTotal = $sbTotal;
                echo '<td><p>'.number_format($sbTotal, 2).'</p></td>';
                $total += $subTotal;
                $_SESSION['cartTotalAmount'] = $total;
                $tax = $row['CatTaxPercent'];
                $taxAmt = (($sbTotal * $tax ) / 100);
                $taxAmount += $taxAmt;
                $amt = 0;
                $cartWeightPerProduct = ($row['weight'] * $_SESSION['cart'][$row['ProdCode']]['quantity']);
                echo '</tr>';
                $totalCartWeight += $cartWeightPerProduct;

                $affComm = $row['ProdAffCommision'];
                $affiCode = $row['AffiCode'];

                $_SESSION['ProductCommission']['Moderator'] = ($sbTotal * $row['ProdModCommission'] / 100);
                $_SESSION['ProductCommission']['Affiliate'] = ($sbTotal * $affComm / 100);
            }
            $totalTaxAmount += $taxAmount;

            $_SESSION['cartWeight'] = $totalCartWeight;

            if ( isset( $_SESSION['credits'] ) && $_SESSION['credits'] != "" ) {
                $cred = number_format( $_SESSION['credits'], 2 );           
            } else {
                $cred = number_format( 0, 2 );
            }

            $sessAmnt = ($total + $totalTaxAmount);
            $totalPayableAmnt = $sessAmnt + $_SESSION['TotalWeight'];

            $_SESSION['sessionTotalPayable'] = ( $totalPayableAmnt - $cred );
            $_SESSION['Presentation']['TotalPayableAmount'] = ( $totalPayableAmnt - $cred );
            if ( isset( $_SESSION['sessionTotalPayable'] ) ) {
                $amt = $totalPayableAmnt;
            } else {
                $amt = "Rs. 0";
            }

            echo '<tr><td><p>Cart Total:</p></td><td><p>'.number_format($total, 2).'</p></td></tr>';

            echo '<tr><td><p>Taxes:</p></td><td><p>(+) '. number_format($totalTaxAmount, 2) .'</p></td></tr>';

            echo '<tr><td><p>Shipping:</p></td><td><p id="shippingAmount">(+) '.number_format($_SESSION['TotalWeight'], 2).'</p></td></tr>';

            echo '<tr><t><p><b>Gross Payable:</b></p></td><td><p><b>'.number_format( $totalPayableAmnt ,2 ).'</b></p></td></tr>';

            echo '<tr><td><p>Applied Store Credits:</p></td><td><p >(-) '.$cred.'</p></td></tr>';

            echo '<tr><td><p>Total Payable Amount:</p></td><td><p >'.number_format( ($amt - $cred ), 2).'</p></td></tr>';

            if ( isset( $_SESSION['PaymentMethod']['NetBanking'] ) && $_SESSION['PaymentMethod']['NetBanking'] != "" ) {
                echo '<tr><td></td><td><button class="f_right tr_delay_hover r_corners button_type_16 f_size_medium bg_scheme_color color_light m_xs_bottom_5">Proceed</button></td></tr>';
            } elseif ( isset( $_SESSION['PaymentMethod']['COD'] ) && $_SESSION['PaymentMethod']['COD'] != "" ) {
                echo '<tr><td></td><td><button id="btnCODPayment" class="f_right tr_delay_hover r_corners button_type_16 f_size_medium bg_scheme_color color_light m_xs_bottom_5">Done</button></td></tr>';
            }

        }
    }
} else {
    echo 'Your Cart Is Empty';
}
```

Comment: would help if you show All the code

Answer (score 1):

You can set your session array by pattern is below then commissions don't overrides

```
<?php 
while($basketCount>0)
{
    $_SESSION['COMMSSION'][$agentID] += $calculatedCommisiion;
    $basketCount--;
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Not that you make it easy to understand.

I'll try one more time.

You must have each product id associated with the respective recipient of the commission.  Assuming the number of products are not astronomical, build an associative array "whoGetsPaid as ProdCode=>PersonPaid for every product. e.g.

Then after each product is processed add:

```
$_SESSION[ProductCommission][$whoGetsPaid[$row['ProdCode']] += ($sbTotal * $row['ProdModCommission'] / 100);
```

Comment: Even I get the same result. But how do I bifurcate the amount so that the respective person gets the correct commission amount ?